# Groupby and filter rows based on multiple conditions in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, filter, group-by

Given a dataframe as follow:

```
store_id item_id  items_sold        date
1          1          0        2015-12-28
1          1          1        2015-12-28
1          1          0        2015-12-28
2          2          0        2015-12-28
2          2          1        2015-12-29
2          2          1        2015-12-29
2          2          0        2015-12-29
3          1          0        2015-12-30
3          1          0        2015-12-30
```

I want to groupby `store_id` and `item_id`, then remove for each group their number of entries are less than `4` and all values of `items_sold` are `0`s.

For removing the groups based on the first condition I have used the code below, now how could I add and combine the second condition with it?

```
g = df.groupby(['store_id', 'item_id'])
df = g.filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 4)
```

The expected output will like:

```
store_id item_id  items_sold        date
2          2          0        2015-12-28
2          2          1        2015-12-29
2          2          1        2015-12-29
2          2          0        2015-12-29
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can get a boolean array of all the rows with `items_sold = 0`, then groupby on this array and check if `all` the rows of a group are `True`:

```
m1 = ~df['items_sold'].eq(0).groupby([df['store_id'], df['item_id']]).transform('all')
m2 = df.groupby(['store_id', 'item_id'])['store_id'].transform('size') >= 4

df[m1 & m2]

   store_id  item_id  items_sold        date
3         2        2           0  2015-12-28
4         2        2           1  2015-12-29
5         2        2           1  2015-12-29
6         2        2           0  2015-12-29
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma you can click the say thanks :-) new feature :-)

Comment: @YOBEN_S yep...:)

Answer (score 2):

Fix your code

```
g.filter(lambda x: (len(x) >= 4) & (sum(x['items_sold'])>0))
   store_id  item_id  items_sold        date
3         2        2           0  2015-12-28
4         2        2           1  2015-12-29
5         2        2           1  2015-12-29
6         2        2           0  2015-12-29
```

Comment: If I also want to remove other columns whose not NaN values are less than 30%?

Comment: @ahbon `g.filter(lambda x: (len(x) >= 4) & (sum(x['items_sold'])>0) & (sum(x['Other'].isna())/len(x)<0.3))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help :)